# Convolutional Neural Networks for Sensor Data

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, convolution

I am reading this paper regarding action recognition based on sensor data. And this paper first transforms the input to spectrogram (time vs frequency, it's like the Fourier Transform of each segment of the input time series but square it). So instead of the time series you are given a matrix of st x sf (st is number of time windows, sf is number of frequency components considered) as input to you CNN.

There is this algorithm:

[image]

Can someone explain this? Especially the formula for CNN, I don't get why you have to convolve the (t-1) and dw.
[image]

Comment: That's not a convolution, just a multiply, with some integer arithmetic to get an index position in `S_g[z]` multi-dimensional array

Comment: @NeilSlater I added an image, please refer to it. It's a CNN that's why it's convolution, I think.

Comment: @mcd: I'm not saying there is no convolution happening. I'm saying the equation you are looking at does not have a convolution between the integer values $dw$ and $(t-1)$ - the author has used `*` as it would be used in a computer program.

Comment: Oh okay :) can you please explain this algorithm?

Comment: I don't understand the algorithm myself (although I might figure out the maths, I don't know the problem domain), I just spotted the issue with your misunderstanding about `*` - that is why I have posted a comment on the question and not a full answer. It may help you to get an answer if you explain what exactly is your confusion when trying to understand the algorithm.

Comment: On a brief second look, I get the impression that the two equations are explaining a 1D convolution across one of the dimensions (I assume the time dimension), and there is no tensor maths shown - the indices used fully resolve everything down to scalar values in the spectrograms. So neither `*` represents a convolution, they are both simple multiplies. The convolution is still happening, just what you have is a recipe that includes the convolution in detail.

Comment: Oh okay, it's really confusing that they used this symbol. So the multiplications are just intermediate operations for the convolution?

Comment: Yes, for example $dw * (t-1) + k$ is the term moving the kernel "window" (width $kw$) across the time dimension.